# Class Methods in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how you can make sure a method can only access and not change private data members in a C++ class instance is the method does not have any arguments.  I am writing a program that draws shapes, and I tried this

```
void drawCircle() const;
```

but I have been unable to determine whether the data members remain unchanged.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring a member-function `const` (like your example) means that it won't change any member variables via (the implicit) `this` pointer.  The compiler enforces this.

So the following won't compile:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void drawCircle() const
    {
        x = 5;  // equivalent to this->x = 5; and this is const here
    }
private:
    int x;
};
```

Of course, it doesn't prevent you playing tricks like casting away the const-ness.